# Use result of IF statement directly in same Statement

Tags: mysql, if-statement

My Statement looks as follows:

```
SELECT *,
IF (valid_till = "9999-12-31 23:59:59", NOW(), valid_till) as valid_till, 
(valid_till - valid_from) as summary
FROM tablename
```

So the output of valid till looks correct, but the value of summary is still calculated by the value of "9999-12-31 23:59:59"

How can I achieve that summary is calculated directly by the valid_till value generated by the IF statement?

Thank you

Comment: You cannot use a column alias in the subquery where it is defined.  You need to repeat the logic or use a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

use sub query for this:

```
SELECT A.*,(valid_till - valid_from) as summary (SELECT *,
IF (valid_till = "9999-12-31 23:59:59", NOW(), valid_till) as valid_till
FROM tablename) as A
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL allows use of in-line variables via "@".  Think of it as each record is processed and := assigned a value, you can use that as basis of next statement (or column computation.  It must be declared first, so that becomes a secondary from alias just for declaration purposes.

```
SELECT 
      *,
      @UntilVar := IF(valid_till = @baseDate, NOW(), valid_till) as valid_till, 
      (@UntilVar - valid_from) as summary
   FROM 
      tablename,
      ( select @UntilVar := now(),
               @baseDate := "9999-12-31 23:59:59" ) sqlvars
```

Notice I'm assigning the "@UntilVar" via the := based on your IF().  Then the @UntilVar - valid_from should get you what you need.